# How to set Gmail profile picture for third party emails?

Tags: gmail, email, avatar, yandex

I have an e-mail address `myname@mycompany.com` and we use Yandex Mail for sending / receiving mails. I also set the profile picture in Yandex Passport but it's not shown in Gmail when I send an e-mail from Yandex to Gmail.

How Gmail find out the profile picture of the emails from third party services? The profile pictures are not included in email payload and e-mail providers doesn't use a global avatar service such as Gravatar. Is there anything that I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method that should work, though I'm unsure that this is the right site for this (possibly SuperUser?), is creating a [Google+](https://plus.google.com/) account with that e-mail address and then adding a profile picture to it.

If you are looking to avoid a Google account, this may not be the best approach, but it's somewhat unavoidable if you want to interact with their system in this way.

Comment: Is it even possible to create a Google+ account with a custom domain email address?  I think it probably require buying Gsuite subscription. Please advise.

Comment: @PrashantGupta Yes, you can sign up for Google+ with any email account. On the sign up page (today, UK) there is a clickable link labeled "I prefer to use my current email address".

Answer (score 12):

After Google closed down G+ for non-G-Suite users the solution given before no longer works. An effective way is now setting up your webmail as an alternate email in your google account settings as explained [here](https://cowbelly.com/gmail-profile-photo)

Comment: Most of the time, it doesn't work and image take time to appear. But it seems problem from google's side, not ours!

Comment: It is discouraged to use external links in stackoverflow.  In any case, this solution only let you use the icon from your main gmail account with you "send as" email account. That doesn't help if for example you add a business "send as" email account to your personal gmail account and want to use a different icon for it.

Comment: Link is now broken too, so even more irrelevant.